# How to customize the segue arrow?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like to replace the standard ">" segue arrow in a UITableView cell with my own image.  How do I accomplish this?  I can't find a way in IB to do it, is there a programmatic way?  I already know how to set a custom image on the left side of the text.

Comment: Total failure to do the slightest bit of research. It's right there in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Comment: My very first question, so I totally expected to be flogged by old-timers :).  I was confused because I couldn't get a handle to the arrow from the IB/StoryBoard. Got it with the more helpful answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has a property `accessoryView`. Just set that to your own custom `UIView` and that will show instead of the little arrow image.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use a CustomCell than the default one. It gives you more freedom to change the background, add multiple images, your custom separator ... 
You can look at this tutorial for more details [Custom UITableViewCell with Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/)

Comment: If all that is desired is customization of the accessory view, though, there's no need to go to the point of creating a custom cell.

Comment: Yes you're right, just a hint in case he'll need more customization.